# project name doesn't change on the remote repository after renaming from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I'm using EGit with eclipse Mars. I have renamed some classes included the project name. When I push the commits to the remote repo., I can see the file names have been changed but the project name is unchanged.

So now I have the new project name on my eclipse but the old project name on the remote repository on GitHub. How can I see the name change on the remote repository?

**EDIT** 
.project file, both locally and remote, has the updated name.

Answer (score 0):

If by project name you mean the github repo name, that one wouldn't change.

An eclipse project name is recorded in the `.project`: if that file isn't ignored locally, the `.project` in your github repo should reflect the new name. Check the output  of `git check-ignore -v -- .project`.

> `.project` files on both local and remote repos have the new name

That means the rename has succeeded.
If you want to see your project locally under a *folder* named after your project, you would need to:

- delete your current project from the Eclipse workspace (simple delete, keeping the data on the disk),
- close eclipse
- rename the folder
- open eclipse
- import the project into your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: .project file in the repo has the new name. I see something strange: java project that i see on project exporer on eclipse has the new name, but the physical folder name is still the old one. what if I manually remove the physical folder name?

Comment: @KillBill then you would need to import that project again (remove it from the workspace and close Eclipse first, then rename the folder)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse keeps the name of the project name in the `.project` file and I suspect that is getting properly modified. If you want to change the folder name in the repository, you may have to fall back to git command line.

Comment: .project files on both local and remote repos have the new name

Comment: I see something strange: java project that i see on project exporer on eclipse has the new name, but the physical folder name is still the old one. what if I manually remove the physical folder name?

Comment: 1. Remove the project from the workspace - without removing the project contents. 2. Quit eclipse, rename the folder and push it to git repo. 3. Import the project again.